# Post a NIFI template via REST?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have multiple nifi servers that I would like to be able to POST templates to via the REST interface from a script

The "/controller/templates" endpoint appears to be the proper REST endpoint to support POSTing an arbitrary template to my Nifi installation.
[image]
The "snippetId" field is what is confusing me, how do I determine "The id of the snippet whose contents will comprise the template"? Does anyone have an example of how I can upload a template "test.xml" to my server without having to use the UI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The provided documentation is somewhat confusing, and the solution I worked out was derived from the nifi api deploy groovy script at https://github.com/aperepel/nifi-api-deploy

Ultimately, to POST a template directly, you can use the following in Python requests

```
requests.post("%s/nifi-api/controller/templates"%(url,), files={"template":open(filename, 'rb')})
```

Where filename is the filename of your template and url is the path to your nifi instance. I haven't figured it out in curl directly but this should hopefully get folks with a similar question started!

Edit:
Note that you also can't upload a template with the same name as an existing template. Make sure to delete your existing template before attempting to re-upload. Using the untangle library to parse the XML of the template, the following script works just fine:

```
import untangle, sys, requests

def deploy_template(filename, url):
    p = untangle.parse(filename)
    new_template_name=p.template.name.cdata
    r=requests.get("%s/nifi-api/controller/templates"%(url,), headers={"Accept":"application/json"})

    for each in r.json()["templates"]:
        if each["name"]==new_template_name:
            requests.delete(each["uri"])
    requests.post("%s/nifi-api/controller/templates"%(url,), files={"template":open(filename, 'rb')})

if __name__=="__main__":
    deploy_template(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: This rest endpoint is for nifi 0.6.. how can we do it on 1.0?

Answer (score 5):

The API has moved in 1.0 to:

`POST /process-groups/{id}/templates/upload`

Example, using Python's requests library:

```
res = requests.post( "{hostname}/nifi-api/process-groups/{destination_process_group}/templates/upload".format( **args ), 
    files={"template": open( file_path, 'rb')} )
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to POST a template to NiFi via cURL you can use the following command:

```
curl -iv -F template=@my_nifi_template.xml -X POST  http://nifi-host:nifi-port/nifi-api/controller/templates
```

This will add the template to the NiFi instance with the same name that the template was given when it was generated.

And the `-iv` is optional - It's just there for debugging purposes.

Comment: This rest endpoint is for nifi 0.6.. how can we do it on 1.0?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Nifi Api to upload a template, to do that follow these two steps:

**1. Get a token from Nifi Api:**

```
token=$(curl -k -X POST --negotiate -u : https://nifi_hostname:port/nifi-api/access/kerberos)
```

**2. Upload the template file using the token:**

```
curl -k -F template=@template_file.xml -X POST https://nifi_hostname:port/nifi-api/process-groups/Process_group_id/templates/upload -H "Authorization: Bearer $token"
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation can be confusing because that endpoint is overloaded and the documentation tool only generates doc for one of them (see [NIFI-1113](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1113)). There is an [email thread](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/nifi-users/201512.mbox/%3CD283D64A.24E3%25chakrader.dewaragatla@lifelock.com%3E) that addresses the import of a template using curl, so between the above answer and the email thread, hopefully you can find the approach that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented a full Python client for doing this in [NiPyApi](https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi/blob/master/nipyapi/templates.py)
Key functions for templates are:

```
 [
    "list_all_templates", "get_template_by_name", "deploy_template",
    "upload_template", "create_pg_snippet", "create_template",
    "delete_template", "export_template", 'get_template'
]
```

The client supports NiFi-1.1.2 - 1.7.1 currently, and NiFi-Registry (which is a lot better than templates for flow deployment)